# Launch a play in playbook based on gather facts

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have this Ansible Playbook with three different plays. What I want to do is to launch the two lasts plays based on a condition. How can I do this directly at playbook level (not using `when` clause in each role)?

```yaml
- name: Base setup
  hosts: all
  roles :
    - apt
    - pip

# !!!!! SHUT DOWN IF NOT DEBIAN DIST

- name: dbserver setup
  hosts: dbserver
  remote_user: "{{ user }}"
  become: true
  roles:
    - mariadb

- name: webserver and application setup
  hosts: webserver
  remote_user: "{{ user }}"
  become: true
  roles:
    - php
    - users
    - openssh
    - sshkey
    - gitclone
    - symfony
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just end the play for the hosts you do not wish to continue with, with the help of the [`meta` task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html) in a `pre_tasks`:

```yaml
- name: dbserver setup
  hosts: dbserver
  remote_user: "{{ user }}"
  become: true

  pre_tasks:
    - meta: end_host
      when: ansible_facts.os_family != 'Debian'

  roles:
    - mariadb
```

And do the same for the web servers.